# How to use partial views in asp.net razor-pages properly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I'm currently working on asp.net core mvc project. There is a main page (cshtml), which contains some data and two partial views in it.

Controller of this page contains action, which returns model to the view (With model binding). I've guessed that 2 more actions in the controller created to return data to both partial views would work just fine. But now my application is not working, because it is trying to pass data from main page to the partial views, creating a binding error (Partial views both has their unique models).

I'm currently using `<partial>` tag to add my partial views to the main view. This tag contains a property `view-data` which would resolve the problem with model binding. But it feels like creating a big union object with a lot of sub-objects to pass it through `view-data` wont be a good practice.

So i'd like to have an opinions on best practices with handling this kind of cases. What is the best way to create pages with multiple separated data like this?

My current opinion is that the best way is to make main view get viable information from the controller and in partial views make it through ajax. But anyway, there is still a question how to bypass this error with the application trying to pass data from main view to partial view (Like if i want to keep model binding in partial view to fill it with ajax).

Comment: You have to create a single model in your controller that contains everything.... and that model has to have two properties each one of the type for each view... so from the main view when you call the partial views you pass the value of the corresponding property... something like this <partial name="MyPartialView" Model="Model.MyPartialViewModel1"/>

Comment: Remmber that the <partial /> tag also has a "model" attribute that you can use to pass a model to it.

Comment: @JonathanAlfaro and there is no other way? It sounds kind'a bad. Like i would have to wait untill this big object gained all the data. It might be 4-5 db requests. I guess make it with ajax is much, much better. But i still dont understand how to bypass this error with binding. Maybe i just have to reject model binding in the patial views at all?

Comment: It is way worst to make it ajax because not only you still have to make the same 4-5 db requests but now you have added two extra http requests on top of that.

Comment: that being said if you want to make it ajax you can create two extra actions on your page or controller and return the partial views... then from the ajax call grab the result and assign it to the contents of a div for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some research i came to the conclusion and found a solution for my problem. `PartialViews` is not made for such cases. `PartialView` always depends on model information coming from its parent View.

Instead, if you want to achieve the same kind of behavior as i do you should use `ViewComponents`. It is completely independent tool which has an ability to make its own data access and build whatever model it needs. You also can access `ViewComponent` anywhere in your views even layouts, and even pass parameters to it by name.

I hope anyone finds this article helpful. Here is official guide by msdn on [how to implement and use view components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-3.1)